# Ignore case in powerbuilder?

Tags: powerbuilder, ignore-case

I am filtering data according to `firstname` so I have written the code `name` to represent an employee's first name.

```
ls_value=string(dw_blood.getitemstring(ll_currentrow, "name")) 
ls_find="fname like '"+ls_value+"%'" 
dw_employee.setfilter(ls_find) 
dw_employee.filter()
```

But the problem is that when I enter 'a', it retrieves records whose names are like *abc, akshay* without showing names like *Akshta,Aman* because it is capitalized.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the column name and entered string with upper() or lower() .